# How to update sum values after variable is updated?

Tags: jquery, auto-update, summary

I have a script of auto calculate which is using a jquery calx script from xsanisty. The code works fine but these problems:

1. The first number is not show in currency.
2. After a checkbox is checked. The total number doesn't change along.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/jquery-calx-1.1.8.min.js"></script>
<form id="booking_form">
  <input id="xChrg" type="checkbox">&nbsp;
<label for="xChrg"> Special Meal (Adult:300/Child:200)</label>
    <br />Adult : <span id="p1">2,000</span>
    <br />Child : <span id="p2">1,000</span>
    <hr />
    Adult : <select name="n1" id="n1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    Child : <select name="n2" id="n2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <hr />
    <span name="total" id="total" data-format="฿ 0,0[.]00" data-formula="$n1*$p1+$n2*$p1" >฿</span> 
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#booking_form').calx({});

    $('#xChrg').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).siblings('#p1').html('2,300');
            $(this).siblings('#p2').html('1,200');
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('#p1').html('2,000');
            $(this).siblings('#p2').html('1,000');
        }
    });
});//]]>
```

I expect span#total to update the number right after the #xChrg is clicked.

This is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/n7X7b/

Comment: Why do you need a plugin to do this simple task ? You're complicating yourself. Just do a function and get the .val() of these three select elements then do the math with your val() elements.

Comment: @edduvs Show me please.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.1.9, you can use `onupdate` callback like this :

```
$('#booking_form').calx({onupdate : function(data){
    //Update your field here
    $('#myField').html(data);
}});
```

Comment: I tried to update my code and plugin to 1.1.9 but it getting worse. here=>http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/n7X7b/1/

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code to use jQuery's onChange method and toLocaleString which will format your currency value.

```
var price_adults = 2500;
var price_children = 2000;
var adults = $("#n1");
var children = $("#n2");
var total = $('#total');

$('#n1,#n2').on('change',function(){
    val = adults.val() * price_adults + children.val() * price_children;
    total.html(val.toLocaleString() + ' ฿');
});
```

Or, see this fork if this gives you any error : [http://jsfiddle.net/H3bFE/](http://jsfiddle.net/H3bFE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I know if this is too late to answer, but I hope this may be useful for the others who have similar problem.

You can try to create hidden input as the wrapper for p1 and p2

the script

```
    <script src="../jquery-calx-1.1.9.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#booking_form').calx({});
        });
    </script>
```

the html

```
<form id="booking_form">
    <input id="xChrg" type="checkbox" value="1">&nbsp;
    <label for="xChrg"> Special Meal (Adult:300/Child:200)</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="p1" data-formula="IF($xChrg = 1, 2300, 2000)">
    <input type="hidden" id="p2" data-formula="IF($xChrg = 1, 1200, 1000)">
    <br />Adult : <span id="p1_shadow" data-formula="$p1" data-format="0,0"></span>
    <br />Child : <span id="p2_shadow" data-formula="$p2" data-format="0,0"></span>
    <hr />
    Adult : <select name="n1" id="n1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    Child : <select name="n2" id="n2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <hr />
    <span name="total" id="total" data-format="฿ 0,0[.]00" data-formula="$n1*$p1+$n2*$p2" >฿</span>
</form>
```

and here is the live sample: http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/sample/so2.html

regards
Ikhsan